# Why do we need to extract the first element of a variadic pack in a C++ alias?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

Consider an alias based on a variadic template, that uses its first element in an expansion expression:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
using AllSame = std::conjunction<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>;
```

If we use this alias by passing the first element separately, the code compiles fine:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
using X = AllSame<T, Ts...>;
```

But simply passing an entire pack doesn't compile:

```
template<typename... Ts>
using X = AllSame<Ts...>;
```

Here is the compile error:

```
error: pack expansion argument for non-pack parameter 'T' of alias template 'template<class T, class ... Ts> using AllSame = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<bool_pack<true, std::is_same<T, Ts>::value ...>, bool_pack<std::is_same<T, Ts>::value ..., true> >::value>::type'
```

Why does the call site have to pass in the first parameter separately, and not just pass in the whole pack directly?

Here is [some code](https://godbolt.org/z/pugt2W) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Interesting to note, if you change `AllSame` to be a template class instead of a template alias, `X` works fine.

Comment: Short answer: class templates can be (partially) specialized, this is why this works for them. Template aliases cannot be specialized, there is no pattern-matching involved to find a specialization.

Comment: Intriguing question... I suppose it's a question for language layers (tag added)